# Chisel UInt negative value error

Tags: scala, md5, negative-number, chisel, uint

I have recently started work in scala, and am required to create an implementation of [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). It is my understanding that MD5 requires unsigned types, which scala does not come with. As I will soon begin Chisel, which does have unsigned types, I decided to implement its library. Everything appears good so far, except when doing the below bitwise operations, my F value becomes -271733879, which causes an error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: UInt literal -271733879 is negative" as UInts can't be negative.

```
if(i<16){
      F = ((B & C) | ((~B) & D))
      g = i
}
```

There is more to the error message, but it is just the trace list of different libraries and classes that had an error because of this error, and thus I did not post it because I didn't think it was important. If it was, I can edit this and post it all.

My B, C, and D values are equal to the lower case equivalents listed below, and it is the first time through the for loop so they have not yet updated.

```
var a0 : UInt = UInt(0x67452301)
var b0 : UInt = UInt(0xefcdab89)
var c0 : UInt = UInt(0x98badcfe)
var d0 : UInt = UInt(0x10325476)
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of my answer, I am using the Chisel 3 preferred `123.U` style for specifying literals rather than the Chisel 2 `UInt(123)` style, but this answer works for either.

There are several ways you could do this:

- Use Scala Long (put `L` at end of literal)

  - `val myUInt = 0x98badcfeL.U`
  - This obviously won't work for larger than 64-bit
- Use [Scala BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigInt.html)

  - `val myUInt = BigInt("98badcfe", 16).U`
- Use Chisel's shorthand for constructing BigInts from Strings

  - `val myUInt = "x98badcfe".U`
  - hex = x | h, dec = d, oct = o, bin = b