# why chisel UInt(32.W) can not take a unsigned number which bit[32] happens to be 1?

Tags: scala, int, bit, chisel, uint

It is defined that `UInt` is the type of unsigned integer. But in such case it seems like the MSB is still a sign. e.g., the most relative QA is [Chisel UInt negative value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507807/chisel-uint-negative-value-error)   which works out a workaround but no why. Could you enlight me about the 'why'?

The `UInt` seems to be defined in chisel3/chiselFrontend/src/main/scala/chisel3/core/Bits.scala but I cannot understand the details. Is the `UInt` is derived from Bits and Bits is derived from Int of `scala`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that this is due to how Scala evaluates things.
Consider an example like

```
val x = 0xFFFFFFFF.U
```

This statement causes an error.
UInt literal are represented internally by BigInts, but the 0xFFFFFFFF is an specifying an Int value.  0xFFFFFFFF is equivalent to the Int value -1.
The -1 Int value is converted to BigInt -1 and -1.U is illegal because the .U literal creation method will not accept negative values.
Adding the **L** fixes this because 0xFFFFFFFL is a positive Long value.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Scala **only** has signed integers, it does not have an unsigned integer type. From the REPL

```
scala> 0x9456789a
res1: Int = -1806272358
```

Thus, Chisel only sees the negative number. UInts obviously cannot be negative so Chisel reports an error.

You can always cast from an SInt to a UInt if you want the raw 2's complement representation of a negative number interpreted as a UInt. eg.

```
val a = -1.S(32.W).asUInt
assert(a === "xffffffff".U)
```

Comment: The real issue is that **Java** only has signed integers. And because Scala is built on top of Java, it has to keep these fundamental settings.